# How to get gmail username into asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

Hello folks when someone login to gmail account and in another tab he open google.
Then you must have seen gmail username displays at the top right corner of the google.
I want the same functionality into my asp.net website. I have searched a lot but could not find any answer. please help if anybody have any idea about it.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Do you want a way to retrieve the currently logged in user, or are you asking for HTML/CSS help to get it in the top right? Or are you asking for how to use Google's OpenID service?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the user's details of currently logged in google user, then use `OpenAuth/OpenID`. For `.Net`, a library is available to do all this task, [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). It also contains exact sample of what you want to achieve. Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365572/how-do-i-retrieve-google-profile-with-dotnetopenauth).

Comment: Hi neeraj thanks for answering my question .But if i click on here(you mentioned in your answer) . i get a code snippet but there is not mentioned anything like which are the reference needs to be added to get the work properly.

Comment: Wait, it had so long i used that library, ok, [here it is](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/tree/master/samples/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms), named `DetectGoogleSession`